# Wireguard resets its DNS settings on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dns, vpn, resolvconf, wireguard

Wireguard resets its DNS settings on restart.

I have WG tunnel with following settings:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.2/32
Address = <public IPv6 ip>
DNS = 2001:4860:4860::8888
DNS = 2001:4860:4860::8844
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = <wg port>
FwMark = <wg FwMark>
PrivateKey = <host private key>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <peer public key>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24, ::/0
Endpoint = <wg endpoint>
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

I've configured the tunnel to run as a service

```bsh
systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
systemctl start wg-quick@wg0
```

Wireguard rejected to run with such configuration and raised error that there is no `resolvconf`, so I've installed it. After installation of `resolvconf` the tunnel works but DNS entries disappeared from config file. I've stopped the `wg-quick.service`, restored the config, and ran service again. And WG removed DNS settings from config again.

This problem exists only on my Ubuntu 20.04 PCs. Manjaro works well with such WG config.

What I am doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Solution found. I had to install `openresolv`, not `resolvconf`. With `openresolv` installed, the tunnel works well.

Source: https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand/issues/1434